# mod_vhost_alias question

Tags: apache-2.2

Is it possible that mod_vhost_alias can read several directories (For example, each users) to find the sites? Like in a hosting setup where different users can create the directories in their home directory?

Answer (score 1):

vhost_alias maps a domain received into a path on the filesystem.  It doesn't read the existing filesystem prior to serving the request to see if the files exist.

However, you can do something like have a stable directory listing of files, and use symlinks or bind mounts in the user directories to point to the actual web directories.

/var/www/domain.com
/var/www/domainb.com

and then

/home/user/domain.com is a symlink or bind mount to /var/www/domain.com
/home/userb/domainb.com is a symlink/bind mount to /var/www/domainb.com

Remember that mod_vhost_alias runs everything as the user running the apache service.  In a shared environment, make sure you know the ramifications for running apache like this.

Comment: Alright, sweet. Any quick ways to automatically make all those symbolic links?

Comment: When the domain is created, create the domain and the user's symlink.  If you are doing it the opposite direction where a user creates a domain directory, uploads content, your script would need to move that to the proper location and leave a symlink in place.  Some FTP software won't properly traverse symlinks which is why I suggested the bind mount.  With a bind mount, you need to update your /etc/fstab so that the mount comes back if the machine is rebooted.